# Latin characters not showing on mobile with custom font in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, font-face

I have a custom font on a Wordpress website, custom font works fine both on desktop and mobile, but latin characters like "ñ", and letters with accents do show on mobile but with a different font. Hope you can help.

I added the unicode-range: U+00-FF; but that doesn't seem to work... hope you can help me. The font does have those characters available in Spanish.

```
  font-family: "Lubalin Graph ECG";
  src: url("https://reconocimientos-axis.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/LubalinGraphECG-Book.eot"); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url("https://reconocimientos-axis.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/LubalinGraphECG-Book.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url("https://reconocimientos-axis.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/LubalinGraphECG-Book.woff2") format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url("https://reconocimientos-axis.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/LubalinGraphECG-Book.woff") format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url("https://reconocimientos-axis.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/LubalinGraphECG-Book.ttf")  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url("https://reconocimientos-axis.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/LubalinGraphECG-Book.svg#svgFontName") format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    unicode-range: U+00-FF;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In many cases fonts don't necessarily have all the available characters as it would involve a lot of extra work for the designer. Especially when the font in question is free. I am not familiar with this specific font though.

Another option that could be causing this issue is the subset you are using in your case. Normally tools like Google Fonts allow you to choose the specific subset of characters you require to reduce the size of the font files.

In this case though, the most probably reason is missing glyphs. It happens with many fonts for me when I try to use characters like á, ó, é...

What could be happening is that the specific font files used by your mobile browser don't have the right glyphs.

Also in case you need them, here are a couple of options on Google Fonts that look pretty similar to your font:

- [Rokkitt Font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Rokkitt)
- [Josefin Slab Font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Josefin+Slab)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick response, but as I mentioned on my question, the font DOES have those characters, I've used it for designs and documents many times. In fact, my client uses the same font on their corporate website, and they use ñ, and letters with accents.

Comment: Ok, then the part that you should check is, what font files is it loading for the mobile version. Perhaps in the process of generating those specific files, the accented characters were incorrectly generated. That's the only theory I have, since some files work and others don't. Normally Safari on iOS and browser on Android use TTF files, so you should check those. Try using a different font just to confirm this theory.

Comment: Also, Legacy iOS browsers use the SVG version of the font. In case the problem comes on older iOS browsers.

Comment: You can check more on that on https://transfonter.org/formats

Comment: Ok thank you very much! So, I downloaded the the eot, woff, and ttf fonts straight from the website of the company (found the link on their CSS files) and replaced the files in my site, and it is still not working. How can I check what font files the mobile version is loading?

Comment: Hmm, I opened axis.com on my iPhone 7, but I can't seem to reproduce your problem. Do you have a screenshot and a specific device this happens on?

Comment: Hey, axis.com is my clients corporate website, the website where I have the issues is reconocimientos-axis.com

Comment: It uses the same font from what I saw, that's what I was referring to.